# How do I determine how many combinations this generates?

Tags: math

I'm currently working on an application where I take varying size groups of objects and I need to determine all the possible combinations those items can make.  I've figured out the code to do it because of helper functions.  but it's driving me nuts that I can't recall the math.  It's been a very long time since I've had to do any of this math and I'm having a hard time finding an example like this online.  So hoping someone here can lend a hand.

Suppose the scenario that someone is trying to determine how many outfits they can generate from the clothes in their closet.  It's not considered a complete outfit unless they have one of each type of clothing.  Given the below items found in the closet.

How many different combinations can be generated.  (Assuming they all match. ;-P)

```
Hats - 3
Ties - 5
Shirts - 8
Gloves - 3
Belt - 3
Pants - 5
Footwear - 2
```

Using a smaller set as an example:

```
Hats - 1
Ties - 1
Shirts - 1
Gloves - 1
Belt - 1
Pants - black, blue
Footwear - black, brown
```

So we end up with 4 outfits.

Hats through gloves always remain the same then it's just the combination of Pants and Footwear.

```
1 outfit with black shoes and black pants
1 outfit with black shoes and blue pants
1 outfit with brown shoes and black pants
1 outfit with brown shoes and blue pants
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they have to have one of each then it's simply the product of each of them, i.e. 3 * 5 * 8 * 3 * 3 * 5 * 2 (i.e. 10800).

Comment: I'd have already accepted this but it's on timeout.  I've been thinking about this for far to long haha!

Comment: Just to add: If they have the option of not wearing them it would be product of (each + 1), i.e 4 * 6 * 9 * 4 * 4 * 6 * 3 = 62208

Comment: Fully naked is an option on that case :))

Comment: Haha, I just went upstairs and showed my wife.. who was also trying to recall.  We both laughed at how simple it was and how long it's been since we've done anything more than try to keep the bank account above $0.

Comment: @Altonymous being able to do basic math helps keep the bank account balance positive ;-)

Comment: Yeah fortunately, for us, so does mint.com  ;-P  Thanks for the help!